# REST API with token based authentication

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, api, rest, token

I want to develop a web site with AngularJS. On the backend side I will use Codeigniter REST framework. I have some security issues and I don't want to start developing without fixing them on my mind.

I don't want to use something like api key because it will be reachable by the client and I think it will not secure my methods on api side. I'm thinking to use token based authentication but I don't know if it is suitable for my case. Do I need to verify the user for every request to server? Or is it enough to use just api key for backend side? And also I am planning to use this api with applications on the different platforms in the future.

I can't decide what to do. If anyone advice me something I will be very appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an API key, however - as you wrote - it's pure protection and easily accessible value - potential abuser just needs to view the source or investigate the queries.

In general REST APIs are secured with tokens. At the beginning of the *session* (not in traditional meaning - rather interaction), client needs to authorize itself and if everything is correct, it will be given a token. This token should be included as a header to all subsequent requests that need protection. You may use simple filter on the backend side that will be protecting selected endpoints via verifying it the token that was sent is valid. This is how it works.

Comment: The [JSON web token](http://jwt.io/) standard is often used for this, and has implementations in most every framework.

Comment: thank you answering the question guys! I also find this [repository](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) it may be useful for you.

Comment: @MarkHughes, as far as I understood, both side need the secret key to use JWT? How does it work na JS env then?

Comment: With JWT, your server-side will create a token containing the applicable identification / roles, then sign it using a secret key. The client-side then provides this token (as an HTTP header usually) each time it makes a request. The server can then check the signature is valid (using its key) which proves the client hasn't tampered with it. There's no need for the client to try and "decrypt" or "understand" the token, it just passes it back.

Comment: Now it does make sense. Thank you very much! How such token is passed to client? After authorization? Or at development time? When it comes to development it may be problematic, e.g. roles are changing..

Comment: @opal You'd normally pass it explicitly somehow - for example, as part of a JSON response to a "login" request. It's up to your client-side code to then store (e.g. in local storage or similar) this token and provide it. In terms of expiring the tokens, you could do that explictly from your server side by returning an "unauthorised" HTTP response, which you'd handle in your client side code by clearing the stored token, forcing a new login in. The logic for *when* you expire it would be down to your app.

Comment: Using filters to check whether the token is valid or invalid is fine. but what to do if i want the basic details of the user from the token? @MarkHughes